# Why does "lambda x: x ()()()()" work?

Tags: python, lambda

I put several `()` after a `lambda`, and Python seems to ignore them rather than throwing an error. Why?

My code is:

```
>>> lambda x: x ()()()()
<function <lambda> at 0x105ca7ed8>
>>> lambda x: x (1)(2)(dfdf)()
<function <lambda> at 0x105cae578>
```

Comment: It'll only be an error if you were to *call* the lambda.

Comment: Because that is perfectly valid Python. It could work, for example, if you passed `class X: def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs): return self` and `dfdf` was in scope.

Comment: The `<function <lambda> at...` should be a clue that all you're getting out of that is a function, which hasn't been called.

Answer (score 2):

Your expression has no syntax errors. There may be a *runtime error* when you call the lambda, depending on `x`, but as it stands, you produced valid `lambda` objects.

Remember that `lambda` has the [*lowest* operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), so all of the expression after it is part of the lambda expression to be executed when you call it.

In other words, you defined the following functions:

```
 def lambda1(x):
     return x ()()()()

 def lambda2(x):
     return x (1)(2)(dfdf)()
```

and it'll depend on what `x` *is* what will happen. Pass in a function that accepts any argument and returns itself and there still won't be a problem:

```
>>> def returns_self(*args, **kwargs):
...     print(args, kwargs)
...     return returns_self
...
>>> lambda1 = lambda x: x ()()()()
>>> lambda1(returns_self)
() {}
() {}
() {}
() {}
<function returns_self at 0x102938bf8>
```

If you expected the lambda to be limited to *just* `x`, you'd need to use parentheses to override the operator precedence:

```
>>> (lambda x: x)()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly fine. Your lambda is a function that expects as its argument a function that can be called, which returns a function that can be called, which returns a function that can be called, which returns a function that can be called. The result of that last call is returned by the lambda.

You'll get an error if you call the lambda with another value.

Maybe your confusion is because you think this means

```
(lambda x: x)()()()()
```

Which will give an error, because you didn't pass an `x`.

But it's actually parsed like

```
lambda x: (x()()()())
```

Comment: s/a function that can be called/a callable/g  - a function is by definition a callable (obviously <g>), but not all callables are functions ;)

Answer (score 0):

Python is dynamically typed so it assumes you know what you;re doing when you define your functions. So if you argument `x` is function which returns function which returns function etc. it will work just fine. So, there is no error here.

Answer (score -1):

Because `x ()()()` is a legal expression.